# How to apply weighted filter to combination?

Tags: combinations

I need to find ordering of combination, Combination examples are as follows:

**User A Selects in this order:**

1. Eye-Brown, 2. Pet-Dog, 3. Diet-Carnivore, 4. Body Type-Thin, 5. Hair length-Short

Total numbers may be dynamic, e.g. there may be more than 5 selections then combination would be different.

From above selection i need to find other users having combination percentage as follows:

**100% Matching:**

1,2,3,4,5

**Then from the 80% Matching, first show:**

Weight is decreasing

1,2,3,4,X h*igher weight as first four matched*
1,2,3,X,5 
 
1,2,X,4,5
1,X,3,4,5
X,2,3,4,5 *lowest weight in 80% match, as last four selected*

**From 60% Matching Users, show in this order:**

1,2,3,X,X
 
1,2,X,4,X
 
1,2,X,X,5 
1,X,3,4,X 
1,X,3,X,5 
1,X,X,4,5 
X,2,3,4,X 
X,2,3,X,5 
X,2,X,4,5 
X,X,3,4,5

**From 40%:**

1,2,X,X,X 
1,X,3,X,X 
1,X,X,4,X 
1,X,X,X,5 
X,2,3,X,X 
X,2,X,4,X 
X,2,X,X,5 
X,X,3,4,X 
X,X,3,X,5 
X,X,X,4,5

According to above combination, i am trying to get formula from which i can sort this data.

I need particular value of individual combination so that i can sort that combination according to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n$ properties, if we define `==` as any boolean string comparison routine such as `strcomp`, $\text int(\cdot)$ casting from boolean to integer (0,1) for converting from the real world into something numerically acceptable, the value of each property is:

$p_i=\text{int}($`property{i}==value{i}`$), i=1 ... n$

And the requested fraction (percentage) is just:
$$
p=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^np_i
$$

EDIT:

Now you need some code, for converting from real world into acceptable values (in Matlab):

```
n=5;
property={'Brown','Dog','Carnivore','Thin','Short'};
value={'Black','Shark','Carnivore','Smooth','None'};
for i=1:n
    pi(i)=strcmp(property{i},value{i});
end
p=sum(pi)/n
```

This will output the value `p=0.2`, because you just fit in the `'Carnivore'` property.

If you output $p_i$: `pi=[0 0 1 0 0]`, showing the function `strcmp` only equals for the third property.

EDIT:
An unique ID could be the sum of the given values:
$$
ID=\sum_{i=1}^n \text{values}_i
$$

Hence ID(`[1 2 3 X X]`)=6 and ID(`[1 2 X 4 X]`)=7.

For sorting, you put both $p$ and $ID$ numbers in a same matrix, and sort according the first then the second columns:

```
A=sortrows([p ID],[1 2]);
```

Comment: can you give example

Comment: using my above values

Comment: I have done matching already, what i need to do is i need to sort that all combination according to above sequence. i need one math formula so that i will get unique value from that i can sort

Comment: the $p$ value is for sorting. You put the integer $id$ of the combination i.e. 1,2,3,4,.... and the $p$ in a same matrix $[p \ id]$, and then sort by $p$ as first column, that is all.

Comment: 1,X,X,X,X   and  X,X,X,4,X   this both combination will give same value but i need first combination in top

Comment: With `property={'1','2','3','4','5'}` the evaluation of $p$ is trivial, `p=0.6` for both. And still you need the ID, a unique sequencial integer, a date, whatever!... Did you know about programming??

Comment: i want to implement this in mongoDB, i want particular unique value for each combination so that i can sort accordingly

Comment: So you want me to write your code?

Comment: according your last edit,  [1,2,3,X,X] = [X,2,X,4,X]

Comment: No i just informed you because you asked me that did you know programming or not. i dont want you to write code if i need code then i would ask in stackoverflow.com but i need math formula for this so i asked here

Comment: in MongoDB, make a column with the ID adding all the `a1,...,an` values, and another column with the `p` value as indicated. Then sort with p then with ID. Only that you will have everything sorted. Paste your MongoDB code if you want.

Comment: i can do with double sorting but i want to do in single sorting for optimization

Comment: Optimizing what?. Then concatenate ID and p in the single expression for pID and sort against pID, which is the same.

Comment: Solved with mongo sort, first i have sort with percentage and then with weight

Comment: Yesss that is the way!!